# unix: Can I delete files in a directory that do not contain text?

Tags: unix

Can I delete files in a directory that do NOT contain any text? These are text files with the extension '.fasta'. Initially I am running this script:

```
for g in `cat genenames.txt` ; do cat *${g}_*.fa > $g.fasta ; done
```

On a list of files that look like:

- id_genename_othername.fa

But in some directories, not all the genenames from the list (genenames.txt) have files with names that match. So sometimes I will get this message:

```
cat: *genename_*.fa: No such file or directory
```

The above code still makes a '.fasta' file with the genename that doesn't exist and I would like to remove it. THANK YOU.

Comment: When you say 'no text' is the file empty, ie. filesize 0 bytes?

Comment: you'd need an `if` of some sort to test if the wildcards matched anything, before doing the catting.

Comment: Yes, the file is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your script is using `#!/bin/bash`, I'd do

```
shopt -s nullglob
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    files=( *"$pattern"*.fa )
    if [[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "no files match pattern *$pattern*.fa"
    else
        cat "${files[@]}" > $pattern.fasta
    fi
done < genenames.txt
```

Comment: This is very close but doesn't always work depending on what is in the folder. For example, my genenames.txt file lists two genes: gene1 and gene2. These are in a text files with new line characters after each gene. If the folder contains files that are id_gene1_othername.fa then the I get the correct output: one file named gene1.fasta with the data concatenated from the original files. But in a folder with files id_gene2_othername.fa, but no files with gene1 in the name, the output is two files named gene1.fasta and gene2.fasta, and are both the concatenated data from gene2.

Comment: In that scenario, are there any files with **both** "gene1" and "gene2" in the filename? Maybe we just need `files=(*_"$pattern"_*.fa)` with 2 underscores

Comment: All files are either gene1 or gene2. As of now the folders in which I am working have had files that are either all gene1 or all gene2, but I will come across folders that have both genes within the folder. But to make sure I am clear, even when both genes are present in the folder, each file is only one or the other.

Comment: Yup! `files=(*_"$pattern"_*.fa)` fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the following?

```
for g in `cat genenames.txt` ; do cat *${g}_*.fa 2>/dev/null > $g.fasta ; done
```

This should prevent the not found errors from producing files

Comment: This gets rid of the error but the empty file is still made.